# How to display Linq to Entity query result in ASP.NET MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a Link 2 Entity query expression in my ASP.NET MVC app:

```
Dim var = From c In context.Evaluation_Template _
          From ae In context.Assigned_Evaluation _
          Join ua In context.User_Assignment On ae.Assignment_ID Equals ua.Assignment_ID _
          Select c.Evaluation_Name, ae.Due_Date, ua.Is_Started, ua.Is_Completed, ua.Is_Approved
```

I want to pass this to the view and display the results.

I have tried

```
Return View(var)
```

But I'm not sure how to iterate through the results.

I'm new to .NET in general so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want strongly-typed objects to use in your view you would need to go into your view and change the top from...\

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
```

to

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage(Of IEnumerable(Of String))" %>
```

Of course replacing Of String with your model type you want to pass in.  To pass in your collection you would use...

```
Return View(query.ToList())
```

... assuming query was some sort of IQueryable query from ADO.NET EF.

Then in your view you could iterate through the results passed in.

```
    <%  For Each s As String In Model
        %><%=s%><%
    Next%>
```

That would output each string in the collection passed into the view's data model.

Though I do recommend for best practices to create a type specifically for passing into your views, aka ViewData.

Answer (score 0):

First it looks like your query is messed up a tiny bit. I am unsure about VB.NET but you would in this case need a separate class because you are selecting something that is not your Entity Framework model.

```
Dim var = From c In context.Evaluation_Template
          .Include("Assigned_Evaluation")
          .Include("User_Assignment")
          Select c
```

This is the third eidt, I keep posting it :) What your view page then needs to take is:

```
IEnumerable<Evaluation_Template>
```

You do this either by generating a strongly typed view or setting it in the page directive of the view page. You could also do what you are trying for (less overhead) but then you would need a separate class to send to the view page.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Do you think you can post example code of how to iterate through the result?

Comment: See below for a bit of VB.NET magic. I would still urge you to create new view and select strongly typed view and then ModelName.Evaluation_Template as the type. Thats the best guide you will get.